# PHP print_r shows array and not plain text only

Tags: php

I am once again looking for some help.

I have found this stopwords script - I basically remove all common words from a string.

```
<?php
$CommonWords = file_get_contents('http://localhost/stopwords.txt');
$CommonWords = explode("\n", $CommonWords);
$CommonWords = array_map('trim', $CommonWords); // <---- ADD THIS LINE
$keywords = 'The <meta> tag’s keyword attribute is not the page rank panacea it once was back in the prehistoric days of Internet search. It was abused far too much and lost most of its cachet. But there’s no need to ignore the tag. Take advantage of all legitimate opportunities to score keyword credit, even when the payoff is relatively low. Fill in this tag’s text with relevant keywords and phrases that describe that page’s content';
$search_keywords = strtolower(trim($keywords));$arrWords = explode(' ', $search_keywords);
$arrWords = array_unique($arrWords);
foreach ($arrWords as $word) {
 if (!in_array($word, $CommonWords) && (trim($word) != '')) 
 {
 $searchWords[] = $word;
 } 
 }
 print_r($searchWords);
 ?>
```

The output for the code looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => tag’s [2] => keyword [3] => attribute [4] => page [5] => rank [6] => panacea [7] => prehistoric [8] => days [9] =>)
```

How can I format it so that the output looks like this: (without the Array and numbers)

```
tag's, attribute, page, rank, panacea, prehistoric, days
```

Thanks

Comment: `print_r()` and its cousin `var_dump()` are really diagnostic tools intended to show the internal structures of arrays and objects. They typically aren't appropriate for friendly output, as you've discovered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) on the resulting array.

```
$myString = implode( ', ', $myArray ); // Results in Item1, Item2, Item3, etc...
```

Comment: excellent, I actually had the same issue a couple of times, and created a work around. This is neat thanks!

Comment: @Gerald You're welcome. PHP has a lot of fantastic native functionality - after nearly 10 years, I'm still learning each week about :)

Comment: If I had a dime for every PHP question to which the answer was `implode()` or `explode()`.  Better yet, if I had 10 rep points.