# any way to remove those Array ( [0] => '..... ' )?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I display the array into a table but those Array ( [0] => ' [1] => [2] => ' [3] => '..... ' ) still remained...is there any way to remove them?

http://jsfiddle.net/yy885/CXcjR/3/

I am using print_r to do the output.

```
print_r($hours);
```

is there anyway to remove those Array ( [0] => ' [1] => [2] => ' [3] => '..... ' ) and leave the table alone?

the code I got so far.

```
echo '<table border="1" class="ieh-fl">';
echo '<tr><td>'.$todaydate.'</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>'.$staffd.'</td></tr>';
$hours = [];

sort($new_arr);
foreach ($new_arr as $value) {

    $part = substr($value, 0, 4);
    $hours[$part] = "<tr><td>".$value."</td></tr>";
}

for ($i = 9; $i < 20; $i ++)
    for ($j = 0; $j < 60; $j += 15)
    {
        $hour = sprintf('%02d%02d', $i, $j);
        if (!isset($hours[$hour]))
            $hours[$hour] = "<tr><td>$hour</td></tr>'";
    }
sort($hours);   
print_r($hours);
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: If you don't want to have the `print_r()` output, remove its call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant, using print_r() will display it as array itself and html for values. this are diagnostic tools intended to show the internal structures .

instead you can use

```
echo implode(",",$hours);
```

similar to this issue

[PHP print_r shows array and not plain text only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234210/php-print-r-shows-array-and-not-plain-text-only)

Comment: Thanks. Indeed this is a much nicer method as it doesnt require an additional loop. Anyway, the next step I am going to do is add a foreach loop outside it for 2 additional mysql query...

Answer (score 2):

Uh, yes. Print the contents instead. And ditch the single quote in your assignment.

```
$hours[$hour] = "<tr><td>$hour</td></tr>";
```

....

```
foreach ($hours as $row)
{
  echo $row;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and nope, its not an assignment. (god, just finished college last year, no way in hell I will go back there for another few years.)

Comment: Uh... when you use "=", it's an assignment.